# Suspicious cast to NotificationManagerCompat

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a notification from a service using this piece of code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notif=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"ID1").setContentTitle("HI").setContentText("THERE");
NotificationManagerCompat man=(NotificationManagerCompat) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
man.notify("tag",notif);
```

However I get this error:

> Suspicious cast to `NotificationManagerCompat` for a `NOTIFICATION_SERVICE`: expected `NotificationManager`

I also tried changing `NotificationManagerCompat` to `NotificationManager` which gives me this error:

> 'notify(int, android.app.Notification)' in 'android.app.NotificationManager' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder)'

Also changing `NotificationCompat.Builder` to `Notification.Builder` requires changing API version to 26 which i'm not planning to do.
any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this example for send notification with notificationmanager

```
private void sendNotification() {
    // Send notifications to watch
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(Integer.toString(mStepsCount) + " " +
                            getResources().getString(R.string.steps))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification_fitwatch);

    // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

    // Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the documentation for `NotificationManagerCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html):

> To use this class, call the static function `from(Context)` to get a `NotificationManagerCompat` object, and then call one of its methods to post or cancel notifications.

So, replace:

```
NotificationManagerCompat man=(NotificationManagerCompat) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

with:

```
NotificationManagerCompat man=NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
```

Comment: now i get:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`
when trying to execute this line

Comment: @Abol_Fa: Presumably, you have this line in a field initializer. Call `NotificationManagerCompat.from()` inside of `onCreate()`, after `super.onCreate()`.

Comment: Here is my onCreate method:
`public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        man=NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    }`
upon calling man.notify i get
 `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`
just to add: man.notify() is being called from an interface implemented by the service.

Comment: @Abol_Fa: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can provide an up-to-date [mcve]. This would include the full stack trace and your current code.

Comment: Fixed the problem by making the notificationmanagercompat and the notificationcompat.builder global and static. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But, `NotificationManagerCompat` doesn't have `activeNotifications`